# How to join get results per day without looping in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am so sorry. I did not ask the question correctly. So here it is again:

I have a table containing number of posts, their destinations and their retrieval dates. What I want to do is for a date range and for each date in the range, find the latest number of posts for each destination that is earlier than the date. This needs to be done in a stored procedure and not looping through the date range. Is it possible? Thanks.

For example:

```
Destination  RetrievalDate       NumberOfPosts
-----------  ------------------  -------------
A            11/1/2011 12:00 AM  1
A            11/1/2011 1:00 AM   5
A            11/1/2011 5:00 AM   6
B            11/1/2011 12:00 AM  0
B            11/1/2011  4:00 AM  2
C            10/20/2011 5:00PM   1
A            11/2/2011 12:00 AM  8
A            11/2/2011 2:00 AM   9
B            11/2/2011 12AM      3
```

For example, in the above table, if the date range is 11/1/2011 - 11/3/2011, I would get

```
Destination  ReportDate  NumberOfPosts
-----------  ----------  -------------
A            11/1/2011   6
B            11/1/2011   2
C            11/1/2011   1
A            11/2/2011   9
B            11/2/2011   3
C            11/2/2011   1
A            11/3/2011   9
B            11/3/2011   3
C            11/3/2011   1
```

Comment: Your edit to the question not only completely changes it but makes no sense. Where does `11/3/20111 5PM` come from in the desired output.

Comment: Forgive me. I was so frustrated with this for the whole day and did not think thoroughly. I'll fix it again.

Comment: Do you have another table that lists all the destinations too?

Comment: Please bear with me. First time posting question here and I was not sure what the best way to describe my problem. And no, I do not have another table that lists the destinations. Actually, the destination in this table is the DestinationID (as integer) but I used alphabets here to make it easier to understand (I thought).

Answer (score 2):

Following your edit you can use

```
declare @start date = '20111101'
declare @end date = '20111103';

WITH Dates(D)
     AS (SELECT @start
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, D)
         FROM   Dates
         WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, 1, D) <= @end),
     Destinations
     As (SELECT DISTINCT Destination
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT CA.Destination,
       CA.[Number of posts],
       dt.D AS ReportDate
FROM   Destinations dst
       CROSS JOIN Dates dt
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM   YourTable y
                    WHERE  dst.Destination = y.Destination
                           AND y.[Retrieval Date] <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, dt.D)
                    ORDER  BY y.[Retrieval Date] DESC) CA
```

Ideally you would substitute another table listing the distinct destinations rather than using the CTE one built from the main table.

Comment: I'll give it a try and let you know the result. Thanks so much!

Comment: When working with a large date range, I got the following error:

The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

It appears to error on the WITH Dates CTE.

Comment: Add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` to the very end of the query